# Error in display the final result of a database query

Tags: php, mysql

Kindly help sort this little problem giving a big bug. I query a database to output a content limit by a number of words. it worked. But I find it difficult to display the full content on another page.
 Below is the database query which worked.

```
<?php 
    require_once ('inc/mysqli_connect.php');// Connect to the db.
    $q = "select id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(description,' ',250) AS responsibity, SUBSTRING_INDEX(qualification,' ',250) AS qualification,(post) AS position FROM career ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15";
    $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

    if ($r) { // If it ran OK, display the records.
        echo '<h2>Open Positions</h2>';

    // Fetch and print all the records:
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
              echo'<ul>';
              echo '<li><a href="http://localhost/sitename/career-details.php?id
='.htmlentities($row['id']).'">'.htmlentities($row['position']).'</a>.</li>';
              echo '</ul>';
        }
        mysqli_free_result ($r); // Free up the resources.  

    } else { // If it did not run OK.

        // Public message:
        echo '<p class="error">The are no latest job openings please. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>';

        // Debugging message:
        echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br /><br />Query: ' . $q . '</p>';

    } // End of if ($r) IF.
     ?>
```

The other page which I find problem with.

```
<?php
$page_title = 'View career details';
require_once ('inc/mysqli_connect.php');// Connect to the db.

$id= $_GET['id'];
$q = "SELECT * FROM career WHERE id= '$id' ";
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

if ($r) { // If it ran OK, display the records.
    echo '<h2>Career Details</h2>';

// Fetch and print all the records:
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
          echo $row['position'];
          echo '<br>'.$row[' responsibility'];
          echo '<br>'. $row['qualification'];
          echo '<a href="apply.php>Apply.</a>';
    }
    mysqli_free_result ($r); // Free up the resources.  

} else { // If it did not run OK.

    // Public message:
    echo '<p class="error">Could not bring you job description due to error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>';

    // Debugging message:
    echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br /><br />Query: ' . $q . '</p>';

      } // End of if ($r) IF.


      ?>
```

is giving error thus.

```
An error occurred in script 'C:\wamp\www\sitname\career-details.php' on line 74: Undefined index: id
```

Am sorry I don't Know how to format coding on this page as I tried all I could not to make it messy. Kindly point me in order.

Comment: very hard to count lines, so specify error line...

Comment: You have a typo here: `$row[' responsibility']`. Remove the space.

Comment: first check if(isset($_GET['id'])){ $id=$_GET['id']; //more code }

Comment: @user1844933, the error is specified at the end of the post. as line 74

Comment: you should also escape the input into your sql strings, otherwise you leave yourself liable to an sql injection attack. For example $id= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id')]) would make your id value safe from an sql injection attack.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)`, won't fix your code, but its a bit shorter than using the constant

Comment: Is this done according to a tutorial from 1999? Last time I looked out the window it was 2014. Things have changed a bit. Well, at least there's an "i" after "mysql". At least some hope.

Answer (score 0):

Add some validation in your code.

```
$id = null;
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
   $id= intval($_GET['id']);
}
$q = "SELECT * FROM career WHERE id= '$id' ";
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($r);
if($rowcount > 0){
   // Fetch and print all the records:
}
```

Also You have some type errors like

```
echo '<br>'.$row[' responsibility']; // '<br>$row['responsibility']
echo '<a href="apply.php>Apply.</a>'; // <a href="apply.php">Apply.</a>
```

Comment: it gives the following errors:<p>An error occured in script 'C:\wamp\www\sitename\career-details.php' on line 74: Undefined index: id

Comment: @ Martian, another error is: <p>An error occured in script 'C:\wamp\www\sitename\career-details.php' on line 81: Use of undefined constant rowcount - assumed 'rowcount'

Answer (score 0):

You use column aliases in your first query:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(description,' ',250) AS responsibity
(post) AS position
```

You use `SELECT *` in your second query. You can only use the original column names in there , not `$row['responsibility']` and `$row['position']`.

Comment: @ Roland Jansen, I did as you requested but don't know why it is not still working, please help